# Check if Column Contains a Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What do I add to the if statement to check if Column `5` in the applicable row contains a value and prevent the setValue() from overriding the old value?

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var i = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'].indexOf(sheet.getName());
  if (e.range.getValue() != '' && i > -1 && e.range.columnStart === 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Add a condition in the `if` statement for column `5` to be empty at `row` in order to fill it:

`sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue()==''`

**Solution:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var i = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'].indexOf(sheet.getName());
  if (e.range.getValue() != '' && i > -1 && e.range.columnStart === 1 && sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue()=='') {
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  }
}
```

**Or:**

I formatted your code a little bit to make it more compact:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const sheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
  if (e.range.getValue() != '' && sheets.includes(sheet.getName()) 
      && col === 1 && sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue()==''){
      e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  }
}
```